# Unable to install coverlet.console 3.1 plugin in vs 2019 .net frame work 4.5.2 project

Tags: console, yaml

In git lab server,I am trying to generate code coverage using yaml file as below script

stage: test
script:
**- dotnet test AMSC\AMSC.sln --logger trx /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=opencover**

I am able to generate code coverage in opencover format in git server.
the job was failed after generating the code coverage as below screenshort,please let me know any one have solution on this.

[code coverage report in CI/CD Pipe line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiBXX.png)
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1